# Should one validate input (for MySQL selects) just for the sake of buffer overflows?

Tags: mysql, validation, buffer-overflow

Assuming that a program will send this statement to mysql server : `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE column_name = ?` , should I validate the input that will be passed to placeholder just for the sake of possible buffer overflows omitted vulnerabilities that mysql could have in it's code ? [Here is a very old buffer overlow for select](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/63895) . There are also some exploitable buffer overflow holes in mysql 5+ , but i guess most of them are fixed. Anyway should one check the input size (or format when any size is permitted) just for the sake of buffer overflows?

P.S. There are many elements/ levels in an application's stack/pipeline that you do not have control over them (before and after you take control over the input). Isn't buffer overflow validation overkill?

Comment: You should always validate for the sake of security

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where this input comes from. If it comes from an outside source you have no control over (for example, the input is typed into a web form), you should definitely validate it and only accept values that may actually appear in `column_name` column.

If you accept values that may never appear in that column (due to invalid characters, invalid length, etc...), it would be a waste of resources to pass the value to MySQL. You can stop it at the source, and require the input to be valid. Therefore, validating the input is a good idea regardless of potential security issues (such as buffer overflows).